# Pass parameters defined “in the buttons”(template) to CRUD-view

Tags: python, django

I have a table, where I add in the last column of every row the buttons “delete” and “edit”. I do this with the url + parameters in the href in the template (see below). I wrote a function for every href + parameter and the scripts work.

```
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="projekt_id" value="{{objekt.id}}" />
                <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" href="{% url 'check:remove_project' objekt.id %}" role="button">delete</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" href="{% url 'check:edit_project' objekt.id %}" role="button">edit</a>
            </form>
```

Since i need such tables very often I want to handle the entire functionality (view the data/edit/delete/create) in one single view (I already have this in one template). My idea/wish is to pass the name= and value= from inside the buttons to the view. There I can distinguish for the appropriate functions - by if-statements- between edit/delete/view/create…

How can the parameters be passed from the BUTTONS in template to the view? Where is the documentation?

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to solve this? (maybe a combination of class based views?)

Comment: This question is unclear. Those are just links styled as buttons, you handle the parameters just like any other URL

Comment: I try to clarify. The code above ist what I use now (url + parameter). What I want is that the buttons are passing e.g. name="edit" or name="delete" to the view (how to write the template, how to read the parameter in the view?). Then I can put the create/read/update/delete functionality in one function-based-view.

Answer (score 1):

You can access a button like any other field in the POST data.

```
<button type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button>
<button type="submit" name="edit"> /Edit</button>
```

```
if "edit" in request POST:
   ...
elif "delete" in request.POST:
    ...
```

Comment: Great! I modified it slightly: in template: <button type="submit" name="modification" value="delete">Delete</button>, in view:    if request.POST['modification'] == 'edit':

Comment: Sure, you can do it either way.